# jQuery : Make Automatically Scrolling Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, sidebar

Can anyone tell me how to implement the scroll 'sidebar' follows the users scrolling the page, but stops when it reached the 'footer'

```
<div id="section">
    <div id="sidebar"> </div>
    <div id="hello"> </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"> </div>
```

Div 'section' doesn't have a set height meaning it grows whenever the div with an id of hello grows. This means that neither the 'hello' nor 'section' has a set height

Div 'section' has a width of 728 and 'hello' has a width of 400. 'sidebar' has a width of 200.

What I  want to happen is (using jquery) when the person scrolls just a little past the sidebar then the sidebar should scroll with the page. Hoever the sidebar should not overlap with the footer.

Therefore sidebar should only scroll along with the page till the end of the div section.

The red block (on my [website](http://www.cyberfanatic.com/)) is the sidebar that want to scroll.

Comment: Have you done any jQuery? If not you should do that research first. If you do know jQuery, then can you post what you've tried please. Thanks.

Comment: Does this need JQuery? Can't you just use fixed CSS positioning?

Comment: Have you looked at scroll (http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and scrollTop (http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)?

Comment: @Brendan, to be cross browser compatible it will have to be.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should get you started (Tested CHROME only): http://jsfiddle.net/MyFB9/3/

### JS

```
var $sb = $('#sidebar'); 
var $foot = $('#footer');
var footerTop = $foot.offset().top;
$foot.html(footerTop);
$(document).scroll(function(){
    //+ 100 since the height of the sidebar is 100px

    if($(this).scrollTop() + 100 > footerTop){
        //when we get close, line up perfectly with the footer
        $sb.css({top:footerTop - 100}); 
    }else{
        //otherwise scroll with the page
        $sb.css({top:$(this).scrollTop()}); 
    }

    //Visualy display the position of the bottom edge of the sidebar
    $sb.html($sb.offset().top + 100)
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="section">
    <div id="sidebar"> </div>
    <div id="hello"> </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"> </div>​
```

### CSS

```
#section{
 vertical-align:top;   
}
#sidebar, #hello{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;    
 vertical-align:top; 
 top:0px;
 left:0px;   
}
#sidebar{
 height:100px; 
 width:50px;
 background-color:red;   
}
#hello{
 height:900px; 
 width:50px;
 background-color:green;   
}
#footer{
 height:450px;
 width:100px;
 background-color:yellow;    
}
​
```

Comment: sorry but that is not what i am looking for i just want the sidebar to position fixed when the user scrolls then i want it to not position fixed when div section is over

Comment: Sounds like you're describing an implementation detail instead of a requirement. I re-read your question again, and I believe the above produces the desired effect (though perhaps not the desired implementation). I'll restate what you want in my own words. "Have the sidebar (the red block) follow the page when scrolling until you reach the footer (the yellow block)." Can you provide any more details on what you don't like about this implementation or what your other requirements are. Thanks.

Comment: yes please take a look at http://www.cyberfanatic.com once again. please make sure you delete your cache before you visit though or hole shift and then press the reload button on your web browser. So i want the red block to scroll down with the page basically position fix then i want the red block to not overlap the footer meaning just stay put on top of the footer basically position relative